# I have the following multilinestring, and I am looking for finding the intersection between each pair

Tags: intersection, python-2.7, shapely

I have a pair of lines, which I like to find the intersect of each of one them with each other. I know for two lines I can do the following:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString

line1 = LineString([(0,0), (1,0), (1,1)])

line2 = LineString([(0,1), (1,1)])

print(line1.intersection(line2))
```

Let's say I have the following multilinestring, and I am looking for finding the intersection between each pair?

```
MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 0 20), (20 0, 20 20), (7.49080237694725 11.97316968394073, 5.67208473076472 5.229834926470677), (19.01428612819832 3.12037280884873, 25.96681259449994 4.024633854021577), (14.6398788362281 3.119890406724053, 21.51766222234933 1.803845175041164))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to combine all possible line pairs extracted from the multiline:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString
from itertools import combinations

multiline = MultiLineString([[(614633.1598889811, 6614684.232110311), (614585.0239559432, 6615176.69973293), (614244.3696605981, 6615210.024609649), (614174.0171430812, 6615058.211282375)], 
                             [(614849.2836035677, 6614574.273030049), (615163.3363697577, 6614591.624011607), (615477.7302093033, 6614608.993836996), (615475.8039105758, 6614892.159749944), 
                              (615474.6318041045, 6615064.459401229), (614967.3343471865, 6615119.389699113)], 
                             [(615054.1363645532, 6614185.399992246), (615163.3363697577, 6614591.624011607), (615227.7403992868, 6614831.207001455), (615475.8039105758, 6614892.159749944), 
                              (615835.3545208545, 6614980.506471327), (615867.958614701, 6615021.869873968), (615474.6318041045, 6615064.459401229), (615474.2581286087, 6615119.389699113), 
                              (615286.7657710963, 6615227.024200648)], 
                             [(616057.5676853136, 6615001.338955494), (615867.958614701, 6615021.869873968), (616067.9839273975, 6615275.633330373)]])


for line1, line2 in combinations([line for line in multiline],2):
    if line1.intersects(line2):
        print(line1.intersection(line2))
```

Will output:

```
MULTIPOINT (615163.3363697577 6614591.624011607, 615474.6318041045 6615064.459401229, 615475.8039105758 6614892.159749944)
POINT (615867.9586147011 6615021.869873968)
```

[image]